# Why do I get a 'Password required' pop-up when I use JGit in an eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, proxy, rcp, jgit

I am using Gitlab as a repository in my RCP app. `gitlab4j` is used to navigate groups and projects and `jgit` is used to clone and fetch.

I set up tokens for accessing the Gitlab API and this works fine.

When I come to clone a repository (using `jgit`), I get a popup which wants me to enter user and password for "GitLab". I can just press `Cancel` and the clone action proceeds and completes successfully.

I have tried the same code outside of eclipse and I have no problem at this point.

I think that it has something to do with the eclipse proxy. How can I programmatically disable the proxy or configure it to ignore my Gitlab URL?

```
Git git = Git
            .cloneRepository()
            .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("PRIVATE-TOKEN", token))
            .setDirectory(dir)
            .setURI("https://my-gitlab-repo")
            .setNoCheckout(true)
            .setProgressMonitor(pm)
            .call();

git.checkout()
    .setCreateBranch(true)
    .setName(DEFAULT_BRANCH)
    .setStartPoint("refs/tags/" + tag.getName())
    .call()
```

*Further info*

I have tried setting `core.net` preferences in `plugin_customization.ini` to define a proxy bybass but this does not help.

```
org.eclipse.core.net/nonProxiedHosts=git1.acme.com|localhost|127.0.0.1
org.eclipse.core.net/proxiesEnabled=true
org.eclipse.core.net/systemProxiesEnabled=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the login credentials to the URL as well as setting the CredentialsProvider and this prevented the login popup.

```
Git git = Git
            .cloneRepository()
            .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("PRIVATE-TOKEN", token))
            .setDirectory(dir)
            .setURI("https://gitlab-user:{the-token-here}@my-gitlab-repo")
            .setNoCheckout(true)
            .setProgressMonitor(pm)
            .call();
```